# Reading data from file with jsondecode

Tags: json, matlab

I am struggling reading some data from a file using `jsondecode` function in Matlab. I have the following data in a text file:

```
[0, [0, 
3, 
1, 
['X3_5', 'X4_4', 'X4_5'],
[0, 0, 1],
[1,
[[1, [-41844328211318033252367, 344173910578922950492160]],
[0, [344173910578922950492160]],
[
[[0, [66782537082182499309963]],
4],
[[0, [-764979303944605824758909685951]],
19105490]
]]]]]:
```

Sometimes when I run

```
% path to  text file
filePath = './myfile';

% Read the content of the file
fileID = fopen(filePath, 'r');
fileContent = fscanf(fileID, '%c');
fclose(fileID);

% Preprocess the content
fileContent = strrep(fileContent, '''', '"');
fileContent = strrep(fileContent, newline, '');
fileContent = strrep(fileContent, ':', '');


parsedStructure = jsondecode(fileContent);
```

I'm having two problems:

1. A different value is stored, e.g., it saves -41844328211318034137088 instead -41844328211318033252367. Why is this happening? How can I save this values as symbolic value instead?
2. In some cases it ignores brackets, e.g., the first list in [[0, [66782537082182499309963]],4] is merged as follows:

```
parsedStructure{2}{6}{2}{3}{1}{1}06.6783e+22
```

```
parsedStructure{2}{6}{2}{3}{1}{2}4
```

I have tried to solve the second problem using several nested if statements. However, I feel it is adding unnecessary complexity to the code and it just fails every time it finds another similar situation. Any advice or suggestion is well received.

Comment: As written in the `jsondecode` documentation, numbers are converted into doubles. And the numbers you need to convert have more sig-fig than the max precision afforded by [double](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) (and Matlab double follows from the same standard you'd typically expect, ~16 sig fig).

Comment: If you have specific (ie. a limited number of) data types and specs that you need to convert from json, it seems better to write a conversion function yourself. You may be interested in [`vpa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html)

Comment: @Argyll You should post this as answer.

Comment: @ImGroot: Good point. And [done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77938099/3181104).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### What happened to the like of `-41844328211318034137088`?

`-41844328211318034137088` has 23 significant digits and on top of that it is signed.

Meanwhile, as stated in the `jsondecode` documentation - subtitle *Algorithms*, numbers are converted to doubles. [Matlab double](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) cannot support as many significant digits and therefore some (ending) digits are approximated.

(*Matlab double follows from the same standard you'd typically expect, and thus supports ~16 sig fig.*)

You may need to write your own decoder if such numbers are typical in your data. Alternatively, you may need to pre-process your text data so that `jsondecode` reads such data into character arrays. For example, `'["4","-41844328211318034137088"]'`.

###### What happened to the like of `[[0, [66782537082182499309963]],4]`?

As shown below, the example text converts the inherent json object almost as expected, with the sole exception being that single-element lists are replaced by those singular elements themselves.

It is indeed mentioned in the documentation that `jsondecode` does not preserve all of the original structure.

[image]

---

If you are writing your own json decoder instead, you may be interested in using [`vpa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html).